# How to create an array with elements of type specified by a Type instance

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection

I have a `FieldInfo`, and I know it's an array so I use its value to declare an `Array` instance, and also get the type of the array elements:

```
void Test(object baseInstance, FieldInfo baseInstanceField) {
    Array a = (Array)baseInstanceField.GetValue(baseInstance);
    Type elementType = TypeSystem.GetElementType(baseInstance.GetType());
}
```

Now I want to initialize a new array of type `elementType` with a specific length using reflection. How do I do this? I later will have to access the elements of this new array.

```
elementType[] newArray = new elementType[34]; //doesn't work
```

> The type or namespace name `elementType' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: I'm using C#. Sorry if I forgot to include that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously it doesn't work because instead of a type definition you are providing a variable (of a `Type` type, which is irrelevant here).

The `Array` class has a method to create an array like you need: [`Array.CreateInstance(Type, int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb3cfh7k(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var newArray = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, 34);
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. By using the CreateInstance method both for a new array as well as for elements to be included, I manged to do what I wanted. Thank you very much!